# Parse AWS VPC flow logs for unique IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, grep, amazon-vpc, vpc

I have a number of AWS VPC flow logs (they are all text files) and need to sift through them to look for unique IPs in a certain range.

I know that I can use the grep command to search through all the files one by one, and to output the results to a new file, but grep shows the entire line containing the search term. What I want to do is once grep finds an IP address that begins with certain first and second octets, I want to copy the two IP addresses and the two numbers following into a new file, and for the file not to have any duplicates.

If I have the following logs:

```
004935:2016-05-08T02:05:42.000Z 2 531988440191 eni-7e2eee06 10.97.14.19 10.98.14.173 2222 52342 6 3 164 1462673142 1462673202 ACCEPT OK

004935:2016-05-08T02:05:42.000Z 2 531988440191 eni-7e2eee06 10.96.14.173 10.97.14.13 3333 52334 6 3 164 1462673142 1462673202 ACCEPT OK

004935:2016-05-08T02:05:42.000Z 2 531988440191 eni-7e2eee06 10.1.8.3 10.2.9.9 3333 52334 6 3 164 1462673142 1462673202 ACCEPT OK

004935:2016-05-08T02:05:42.000Z 2 531988440191 eni-7e2eee06 10.96.14.173 10.99.14.13 3333 52334 6 3 164 1462673142 1462673202 ACCEPT OK

004935:2016-05-08T02:05:42.000Z 2 531988440191 eni-1f0eee06 10.96.14.173 10.99.14.13 3333 52334 6 3 164 1462673142 1462673202 ACCEPT OK
```

... I'd like to use grep to search for all the IPs starting with 10.97. and starting with 10.96.

Based on these sample logs, I'd like to see the following in a new text file (without empty lines):

```
10.97.14.19 10.98.14.173 2222 52342

10.96.14.173 10.97.14.13 3333 52334
```

So far, I have the command:

```
grep -r '10\.97\.\|10\.96\.' * > ../results.log
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to getting the rest?

Answer (score 0):

A crude way, but i guess it should help. 
`grep -ir '10\.97\.\|10\.96\.' /tmp/<yourfiles> | awk '{print $5, $6, $7, $8}' > /results.log`

Comment: That won't eliminate duplicates and you don't need grep when you're using awk since awk can do anything useful that grep can do.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted expected output doesn't match your description of what you want to do as it's missing the `10.96.14.173 10.99.14.13 3333 52334` line. This does what you described:

```
$ awk '{$0=$5 FS $6 FS $7 FS $8} /(^| )10\.9[67]\./ && !seen[$0]++' file
10.97.14.19 10.98.14.173 2222 52342
10.96.14.173 10.97.14.13 3333 52334
10.96.14.173 10.99.14.13 3333 52334
```

If that's not what you want then edit your question to clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool that does exactly this in the AWS marketplace and it's cheap. It's a good add-on to make the logs actually usable. May be worth checking out: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B074N3YQ1P